# Why does waze deeplink not work in asynctask?

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, waze

#### background

am trying to launch waze with following intent from an asynctask onPostExecute after the task geocodes an address, but it is not working. the link works fine, it as ill explain, it has something todo with launching an intent from the onPostExecute
says cannot resolve intent in logcat.

class declaration:

```
public static class WazeAsyncLaunch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Intent> {
    Context mContext = null;
    public WazeAsyncLaunch(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }
```

this is the doInBackground

```
protected Intent doInBackground(String... addresses) {

    //does geocoding here, i give short version
    Uri intentURI = Uri.parse("https://waze.com/ul?ll=48.8566969,2.3514616&navigate=yes");
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    mapIntent.setData(intentURI);
    mapIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    mapIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    return mapIntent;
}
```

and here is onPostExecute, where the error is happening

```
protected void onPostExecute(Intent result) {
    mContext.startActivity(result);
}
```

i call it from a button onclick event handler in mainactivity like this

```
new WazeAsyncLaunch(MainActivity.this).execute(address);
```

based on community pointer i also tried this in my onPostExecute, to no avail

```
String url = "https://www.waze.com/ul?ll=40.75889500%2C-73.98513100&navigate=yes&zoom=17";
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( url ) );
startActivity( intent );
```

interestingly, also doesnt work when i do:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d https://waze.com/ul?ll=48.8566969,2.3514616&navigate=yes
```

but it does work when i do:

```
adb shell am start -d https://waze.com/ul?ll=48.8566969,2.3514616&navigate=yes
```

it also works when i click this link on my phone
https://waze.com/ul?ll=48.8566969,2.3514616&navigate=yes

#### pointers:

there is no browser installed on the device. (only waze).

--in the manifest of waze is following intent filter:

```html
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
   <data android:scheme="http"/>
   <data android:scheme="https"/>
   <data android:host="www.waze.com"/>
   <data android:host="waze.com"/>
   <data android:pathPattern="/ul.*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

so dont know why my code is not working, however given the fact of adb and link click, i see the intent works when only the data is passed without category and action.
but i do not know how to launch an intent in java with only data and no other properties.

#### question

how can i launch an intent from java with only a data string?
or if theres another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is full working code according.
1 first make a class like below

```
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class WazeClass{

    public static Context mContext;
    public static String address;
    public WazeClass(Context context,String waddress) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
        address = waddress;
    }



    public static class WazeShow extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Intent>
    {

        public WazeShow(Context applicationContext) {
            mContext = applicationContext;
        }

        @Override
        protected Intent doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String url = "https://www.waze.com/ul?ll=40.75889500%2C-73.98513100&navigate=yes&zoom=17";
            Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( url ) );
            return intent;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Intent intent) {
            super.onPostExecute(intent);
            try
            {
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch ( ActivityNotFoundException ex  )
            {
                // If Waze is not installed, open it in Google Play:
                Intent playintent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "market://details?id=com.waze" ) );
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

then call from anywhere fragment or activity.if call from fragment use getContext();

```
new WazeClass.WazeShow(getApplicationContext()).execute("address");
```

Comment: to summarize: essentially, @shakac is telling me to use ApplicationContext instead of MainActivity.this; which is a working answer. thanks

Comment: Welcome my friend

Answer (score 0):

Change your intent like below code

```
try
{

  String url = "https://www.waze.com/ul?ll=40.75889500%2C-73.98513100&navigate=yes&zoom=17";
  Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( url ) );
  startActivity( intent );
}
catch ( ActivityNotFoundException ex  )
{
  // If Waze is not installed, open it in Google Play:
  Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "market://details?id=com.waze" ) );
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: this works fine from mainactivity, but i need it in asyncTask onPostExecute. i will update question. for some reason not working still. thanks for the quick response. unfortunately it is taking me to the play store, not launching waze

Comment: because you don't have waze installed so it will send you to the play store to install waze.

Comment: i have waze installed, your code works fine when i run from mainactivity, but not from asynctask. i dont know, why. updated my question to better explain